# A way to display percentage of video loaded in flutter video_player?

Tags: flutter, video-streaming

Is there a way to show the percentage of video that has been loaded during buffer in flutter using the [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) library?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation, I could not find any way to read the percentage loaded of the video asset. Usually a 3rd party would expose this as a function, then you would capture this result, pass it into a progress bar widget, and reload the state of the entire video widget.

This is a **feature request** and is something you need to ask google to add to.
Just go to the **video_player**'s repository and create a new issue. Someone will eventually help you with this:
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/video_player/video_player

Answer (score 0):

**Show the video progress bar in the bottom of the video.**

```
VideoProgressIndicator(videoController, allowScrubbing: true)
```

**To show the video seconds and minutes:**

First you can create a function to calculate and format the duration for you.

```
getVideoPosition() {
    var duration = Duration(milliseconds: videoController.value.position.inMilliseconds.round());
    return [duration.inMinutes, duration.inSeconds].map((seg) => seg.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')).join(':');
}
```

Once you have created, call the function where you want.

E.g:

```
Text(getVideoPosition());
```